# 8086 - Maze with Dot Matrix Display Output

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I was trying to do my homework but I am stuck at something. We have a Emulation Kit which includes some display kits like ASCII LCD display or Seven Segment Display.

What I'm trying to do is creating a maze on Dot Matrix Display Output. (I did it). My task is place a dot on the kit that tries to find a way out of the maze automatically in 3 minutes. If the dot can’t get out in 3 minutes, my program should prints a message like “I couldn’t get out” on ASCII LCD Display Output.

Here's the maze:

[image: maze]

Also there is an algorithm

- First, the dot must move to right.
- If an obstacle occurs, it must move up. At each step while going up,the dot must check if right direction is available.
- If it is available, move to right.
- If up and right is not available, third choice is down direction. The dot moves down and still checks if right is available at each step.
- The last choice is the left direction. If the dot cannot move down and right when it hit an obstacle, it must move left. While going left, at each step the dot must check if up or down direction is available in given order.

These is my code so far:

```
org 100h    


;-----Data Section-----; 
;#start=Emulation Kit.exe# 
MOV DX, 2000h 
CALL MAZE_1    
MOV DX, 2005h
CALL MAZE_2 
MOV DX, 200Ah
CALL MAZE_3
MOV DX, 200Fh
CALL MAZE_4
MOV DX, 2014h
CALL MAZE_5
MOV DX, 2019h
CALL MAZE_6
MOV DX, 201Eh
CALL MAZE_7
MOV DX, 2023h
CALL MAZE_8 

MOV DX, 2000h 
MOV AL , 00101111b; Dot's position 
MOV Maze1[0],AL
OUT DX,AL 



;-----Code Section-----; 



MOV DI,0  
MOVERIGHT: 
TEST Maze1[DI+1],00100000b ; checks next bit is obstacle or not
JNZ MOVEUP ; obstacle occurs if AL>0
ADD Maze1[DI+1], 00100000b ; moves next column 
SUB Maze1[DI],00100000b ; updates previous column  
INC DI
MOV DX,2000h
CALL MAZE_1
LOOP MOVERIGHT


MOVEUP: 
TEST Maze1[DI+1],00010000b
JNZ MOVELEFT:
ADD Maze1[DI],00001000b 
SUB Maze1[DI], 00010000b
MOV DX,2000h
CALL MAZE_1
LOOP MOVEUP

MOVEDOWN:
TEST Maze1[DI-1],01000000b
JZ MOVELEFT
ADD Maze1[DI],01000000b
SUB Maze1[DI],00100000b 
MOV DX,2000h
CALL MAZE_1
LOOP MOVEDOWN

MOVELEFT:
TEST Maze1[DI-1],00100000b
JNZ EXIT
CMP DI,0
JE MOVEDOWN:
ADD Maze1[DI-1],00100000b
SUB Maze1[DI],00100000b
DEC DI
MOV DX,2000h
CALL MAZE_1
LOOP MOVELEFT



EXIT:


ret 

Maze1 db 00001111b,01000001b,01011001b,01010001b,01110111b,01110101b,01000001b,01011101b,01001001b,01100110b,01001110b,01000001b,01011101b,01000011b,01110001b, 01000011b,01011101b,01010001b,01000001b,01110111b,01000010b,01011110b,01000001b,01111010b,01000001b, 00100011b,01001101b,01000001b,01001001b,01001011b,01110011b,01000001b,01011101b,01001001b,01001011b,01110010b,01011001b,01000101b,01010001b,00001110b
Posy db 01000000b,00100000b,00010000b,00001000b,00000100b,00000010b,00000001b ; Possibilities on y axis

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
MAZE_1 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,0
NEXTM1:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM1
RET
MAZE_1 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;             
MAZE_2 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,5
NEXTM2:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM2
RET
MAZE_2 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
MAZE_3 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,10
NEXTM3:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM3
RET
MAZE_3 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;     
MAZE_4 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,15
NEXTM4:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM4
RET
MAZE_4 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
MAZE_5 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,20
NEXTM5:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM5
RET
MAZE_5 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
MAZE_6 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,25
NEXTM6:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM6
RET
MAZE_6 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;   
MAZE_7 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,30
NEXTM7:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM7
RET
MAZE_7 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
MAZE_8 PROC
MOV CX,5
MOV SI,35
NEXTM8:
MOV AL, Maze1[SI]
OUT DX,AL
INC SI
INC DX
LOOPNE NEXTM8
RET
MAZE_8 ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I have a few problems. First, my program goes right if any obstacles occurs go up etc etc. But it does that only for 1 line (on the x axis). How should I code for y axis? Also I know that it doesn't do that according to algorithm because I couldn't finished it.

Second, I have a `Posy` array in code as you can see but SI and DI registers are full. How can I iterate array with BX register, is there any way to do it without using SI or DI?

Third, is there any easy way to achieve this task? What should I do? (I don't want any code but if anyone wants to try it why not?) Because I have to write these codes for 8 different ports. Any correction or help appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can check bits with the `TEST` instruction for example.

Comment: Yeah I know `TEST` instruction but can i check specific bits with it ? For example Maze1's 4th bit's value? Thanks for comment btw

Comment: Yes, you can. What use would it be if you couldn't?

Comment: Thank you so much then i'll give it a try. Will reply the result here :)

Comment: Fourth bit is in binary `0000_1000` = `8` [hexa]decimal. Fifth bit is `0001_0000` = `16` decimal = `0x10` hexadecimal, etc...

Comment: I understood your approach and i know that. But as you can see in the code,for example " `Maze1 db 00001111b,01000001b,01011001b,01010001b,01110111b` " is an array and each bit specifies there is dot or not.My task is check these dots "automatically" and i don't know if i can do something like this "Is Maze1[2]'s 6th bit 0 or 1? If 0 go right if not go up" so your approach doesn't help me so much :(

Comment: `test [Maze1+2], 0b01000000; jz go_right`

Comment: Thanks so much that's the answer i'm looking for. I improved it a little bit and i realised that i should use bitwise operations (and , or , xor , test etc.)